# What is marker frequency?

Tags: frequency

I am in process of taking "Spectrum Analysis Fundamentals" Keysight online course. In the slide below, marker frequency is mentioned. What is that exactly? I cannot find a good definition online.

[image: Marker Frequency]

Comment: It's equivalent to the cursors on a oscilloscope.  Just  a way to mark/measure a point on the graph.

Answer (score 6):

A marker is a symbol placed on the screen of the spectrum analyzer used to highlight a frequency component of interest. Its frequency is accurately measured by the analyzer. This allows precise determination of frequencies of interest such as modulation rates, harmonics, etc.